# Do I only get one chance at passing Gracie's fashion check?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Gracie finally, well, graced my town today for the first time! I was nervous about passing her fashion check, but I decided to go ahead and try it anyway with only a mere two items (Basketball Shorts and a Hockey Mask for a Sporty theme). I managed, despite kind of looking like a sporty serial killer.

[image: my mayor dressed in sporty/scary clothing]

Gracie doublechecks whether you want to actually go ahead with a fashion check, which makes me wonder if I only get one chance when she's there in my town for the day. She does mention that she is there for the entire day, so I imagine I'd have time to order something from my catalog if I were worried about not passing the check.

I know that you don't get a second chance after *successfully* passing the check because I tried talking to her afterwards and she didn't give me one. But do I get another chance if I fail the first time?

Comment: I think I heard you can retry a few times but haven't verified myself

Comment: Did she give you the mushroom test?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, she gives you two more chances. If you fail three checks, you'll have to wait until she visits the town again.

Answer (score -4):

Actually you have unlimited chances. I just asked her around 10 times because I couldn't pass the rocknroll theme.